# PHP Contact Form POST_Method

Tags: php, html

I am trying to build a really simple Contact form for my personal website

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  echo $_POST["name"];
  echo $_POST["email"];
}
?>


<html>
<body>
   <form action="" method="post">
    <p>
      <label for="name"> Name: </label><br>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </p>

     <p>
      <label for="email"> Email: </label><br>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
     </p>

  <p>
      <label for="message"> Message: </label><br>
       <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
   </p>

   <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

However, nothing appears when I try to echo the post value after pressing submit. I tried using get instead of post and I can see the data from the input field appearing in my URL.

What went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Add `name='submit'` to your submit button..

The first line checking for the submit button doesn't get executed as your html form doesn't have the `name` attribute on the submit button.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have no luck echoing does two value after giving a name to submit. could it be something wrong with my complier?

Answer (score 1):

You should give a name to submit  button. like below

```
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a name attribute in your submit button. Because PHP uses the name attribute as the variable identifier in $_POST array.

So that it would look like: `<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />`

Finally your code would look like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  echo $_POST["name"];
  echo $_POST["email"];
}
?>


<html>
<body>
   <form action="" method="post">
    <p>
      <label for="name"> Name: </label><br>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </p>

     <p>
      <label for="email"> Email: </label><br>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
     </p>

  <p>
      <label for="message"> Message: </label><br>
       <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
   </p>

   <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
    </p>
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```